# Using flush log on MySQL doesn't seem to work, even though I have the privilege?

Tags: mysql

A bit of information:

```
select current_user: 
root@127.0.0.1

show grants for current_user(): 
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'omitted'

Service string:
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\my.ini" MySQL
```

Basically, I do not see any new files. The two files (.log and server_name.log) continue to grow and no occurence of *-old show up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FLUSH LOGS in MySQL only affects binary logs.

[According to this excerpt from the MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html):

> Closes and reopens all log files. If binary logging is enabled, the
>   sequence number of the binary log file is incremented by one relative
>   to the previous file. On Unix, this is the same thing as sending a
>   SIGHUP signal to the mysqld server (except on some Mac OS X 10.3
>   versions where mysqld ignores SIGHUP and SIGQUIT).
>
> If you execute FLUSH LOGS and mysqld is writing the error log to a
>   file (for example, if it was started with the --log-error option), log
>   file renaming occurs as described in Section 5.2.1, “The Error Log”.

IMHO, as a MySQL DBA these past 7 years, I have personally NEVER SEEN this work on error logs, but only binary logs.

[In the latest MySQL Docs concerning MySQL 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-log.html):

> If you flush the logs using FLUSH LOGS or mysqladmin flush-logs and
>   mysqld is writing the error log to a file (for example, if it was
>   started with the --log-error option), the effect is version dependent:
>
> As of MySQL 5.5.7, the server closes and reopens the log file. To
>   rename the file, you can do so manually before flushing. Then flushing
>   the logs reopens a new file with the original file name. For example,
>   you can rename the file and create a new one using the following
>   commands:

```
shell> mv host_name.err host_name.err-old
shell> mysqladmin flush-logs
shell> mv host_name.err-old backup-directory
```

> On Windows, use rename rather than mv.
>
> Prior to MySQL 5.5.7, the server renames the current log file with the
>   suffix -old, then creates a new empty log file. Be aware that a second
>   log-flushing operation thus causes the original error log file to be
>   lost unless you save it under a different name. On Windows, you cannot
>   rename the error log while the server has it open before MySQL 5.5.7.
>   To avoid a restart, flush the logs first to cause the server to rename
>   the original file and create a new one, then save the renamed file.
>   That also works on Unix, or you can use the commands shown earlier.
>
> No error log renaming occurs when the logs are flushed in any case if
>   the server is not writing to a named file.

Again, I repeat, I have personally NEVER SEEN this work on error logs, but only binary logs.

My employer's clients have this bash scripted.